# How do I keep the solid objects visible when viewed through transparent objects?

Tags: transparency

[image]Transparency works for the background but solid objects disappear behind the transparent object.
I'm new to this and watched a load of tutorials but I don't see what I'm missing.

This is my issue here:
As you can see, this has a glass/transparent panel on the front.
The unit the glass is attached to should be visible.

This is what I've used for the transparent object. I based it from another tutorial to get this transparent effect:
[image]

This is what I've got for the solid object:
[image]

Let me know if anyother screenshots would help.
I know I'm showing my full noob colours here but I appreciate anyone taking the time to check this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, if you are in Eevee make sure that the object you want to see is opaque, but maybe show some screenshot, or even share your object

Comment: @moonboots I updated my post. As far as I know I'm using "All" instead of eevee or cycles. I can't really share the object since it's not really mine to share and I'm helping out a mate with it.

Comment: If you have selected the Eevee render engine, for your solid object, in the Shader Editor, open the N panel > Options > Settings > Blend Mode > Make sure that it is set to Opaque, and for the glass object enable Screen Space Refraction, and in the Render panel enable Screen Space Reflections and Refraction

Comment: @Moonboots you absolute star. You're a saint and a scholar! Thanks very much for taking the time to help me. That worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have selected the Eevee render engine, for your solid object, in the *Shader Editor*, open the *N panel > Options > Settings > Blend Mode >* make sure that it is set to *Opaque*, and for the glass object enable *Screen Space Refraction*, and in the *Render* panel enable *Screen Space Reflections* and *Refraction*.